# Realtime ECG Data plotting using ECharts

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I am using ECharts for creating a live ECG Monitor. I started with dynamic data example, https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dynamic-data2

and modified the data to simulate ECG data.

[image]

**How I rendered ECG data?**

I used 2 line series and filled data from a ECG data array. Basically splitting the ECG data to 2 sub arrays.

```js
var EcgData=[ 905,923,950,979,997,1033,1090,1157,1232,1320,1398,1495,1613,1736,1866,2011,2170,2331,2499,2683,2880,3085,3291,3490,3689,3906,4123,4320,4503,4671,4815,4946,5048,5121,5172,5197,5195,5173,5111,5024,4924,4792,4637,4469,4283,4081,3878,3674,3451,3230,3018,2819,2606,2403,2213,2031,1868,1723,1558,1396,1254,1101,921,726,497,251,1,-280,-585,-858,-1058,-1159,-1133,-946,-546,170,1225,2521,3993,5614,7314,9024,10649,11994,12978,13593,13841,13662,13084,12019,10582,8884,7036,5148,3310,1609,111,-1032,-1871,-2389,-2648,-2674,-2518,-2206,-1825,-1410,-1002,-615,-255,56,298,467,612,732,844,939,1010,1088,1174,1268,1353,1447,1537,1631,1758,1874,2010,2148,2287,2443,2607,2771,2931,3111,3280,3465,3660,3837,4028,4239,4444,4650,4851,5053,5268,5491,5683,5879,6068,6248,6415,6565,6699,6844,6993,7129,7251,7361,7458,7537,7581,7577,7544,7485,7404,7306,7190,7055,6920,6783,6637,6478,6295,6106,5905,5708,5498,5279,5050,4817,4590,4364,4138,3910,3680,3480,3272,3068,2868,2674,2486,2310,2145,1963,1786,1634,1500,1374,1256,1138,1021,921,849,771,684,615,557,510,465,426,384,353,333,312,288,272,272,275,282,287,290,291,294,300,306,304,306,304,311,313,316,318,311,309,308,316,312,316,320,323,331,341,340,340,346,354,373,394,413,432,458,473,494,512,513,519,519,520,525,531,536,538,541,537,541,544,542,551,553,551,554,568,587,607,630,648,672,697,721,732,734,735,740,743,739,743,747,744,748,748,753,751,750,751,750,757,766,786,802,823,846,864,885,907,934,961,986,1020,1062,1121,1181,1262,1350,1437,1537,1649,1774,1913,2077,2245,2405,2590,2781,2975,3173,3378,3582,3792,4007,4205,4396,4582,4757,4901,5013,5100,5164,5214,5239,5235,5189,5112,5018,4908,4773,4615,4424,4223,4023,3827,3612,3389,3166,2960,2752,2545,2343,2152,1985,1823,1665,1495,1349,1206,1063,885,677,440,174,-103,-402,-695,-974,-1146,-1203,-1096,-798,-242,580,1711,3060,4632,6310,8039,9725,11249,12511,13385,13882,13910,13523,12703,11496,9972,8199,6283,4404,2614,1012,-352,-1409,-2173,-2592,-2708,-2639,-2404,-2067,-1664,-1243,-828,-463,-140,136,357,519,656,773,869,948,1027,1098,1175,1270,1370,1463,1564,1681,1792,1915,2058,2194,2338,2500,2659,2821,3002,3181,3366,3562,3745,3925,4119,4319,4525,4738,4946,5148,5373,5581,5777,5975,6162,6334,6498,6645,6776,6926,7084,7219,7337,7436,7510,7562,7595,7577,7531,7454,7370,7264,7157,7031,6894,6745,6584,6413,6226,6034,5832,5620,5400,5177,4955,4734,4509,4279,4048,3824,3608,3404,3196,2988,2782,2589,2402,2214,2043,1872,1702,1550,1419,1291,1164,1061,956,863,790,704,629,562,513,462,405,359,329,312,290,275,260,252,254,246,242,240,243,240,234,236,242,247,250,253,253,261,266,265,265,271,273,271,277,276,279,282,285,284,285,284,280,291,311,331,352,373,393,414,436,448,454,454,450,446,454,458,457,465,466,472,478,489,487,490,496,493,494,509,530,551,576,597,619,637,652,659,661,663,659,664,662,665,671,670,671,671,675,675,674,675,678,682,694,716,732,746,773,793,813,836,860,876,901,940,983,1050,1127,1213,1299,1389,1500,1625,1760,1896,2044,2208,2377,2567,2764,2958,3164,3371,3576,3788,4000,4198,4384,4557,4711,4844,4960,5029,5091,5118,5118,5096,5042,4957,4850,4723,4566,4399,4219,4024,3824,3617,3397,3170,2965,2767,2551,2337,2139,1958,1798,1656,1493,1334,1192,1048,880,685,467,224,-41,-330,-629,-915,-1137,-1265,-1279,-1135,-736,-66,938,2190,3648,5257,6956,8687,10325,11722,12785,13483,13811,13702,13185,12197,10793,9127,7288,5387,3509,1767,230,-988,-1878,-2455,-2767,-2836,-2711,-2415,-2035,-1626,-1212,-821,-458,-144,111,289,438,572,695,791,872,948,1023,1114,1205,1293,1379,1481,1599,1715,1856,2002,2141,2295,2457,2612,2779,2964,3142,3321,3512,3688,3880,4088,4291,4491,4698,4902,5118,5342,5537,5731,5925,6113,6279,6438,6581,6719,6875,7012,7135,7239,7342,7411,7457,7467,7445,7392,7324,7235,7125,6996,6865,6730,6578,6417,6240,6048,5844,5641,5433,5213,4985,4753,4524,4291,4062,3833,3606,3389,3185,2981,2770,2576,2397,2227,2055,1886,1712,1548,1417,1288,1160,1031,916,804,722,642,551,479,415,368,319,278,237,206,189,169,147,132,129,125,125,126,125,122,120,123,123,126,134,139,142,145,160,165,167,170,166,169,176,175,169,165,168,163,166,166,163,168,184,200,218,242,263,283,310,333,337,337,342,342,342,346,349,349,351,355,357,362,364,362,357,360,365,374,402,422,442,467,491,510,533,551,546,548,551,553,556,554,551,547,555,556,556,559,558,563,565,570,569,589,614,629,652,669,695,718,742,760,776,806,843,898,969,1046,1129,1222,1328,1438,1557,1691,1838,2006,2175,2350,2539,2735,2942,3149,3347,3547,3762,3967,4163,4344,4512,4657,4786,4875,4947,4997,5020,5017,4979,4908,4814,4714,4583,4429,4254,4057,3858,3655,3444,3213,2978,2752,2536,2323,2125,1940,1769,1619,1469,1305,1157,1014,862,685,475,236,-21,-283,-582,-873,-1153,-1350,-1427,-1357,-1100,-598,172,1260,2603,4138,5824,7551,9256,10808,12142,13066,13608,13719,13392,12652,11525,10031,8285,6388,4492,2681,1037,-382,-1512,-2302,-2784,-2939,-2890,-2677,-2352,-1956,-1536,-1115,-731,-398,-119,102,276,420,541,641,724,789,861,944,1034,1124,1218,1311,1422,1551,1673,1813,1955,2101,2265,2426,2586,2747,2928,3111,3301,3491,3667,3857,4056,4266,4477,4677,4877,5091,5305,5507,5707,5891,6065,6225,6379,6519,6664,6817,6952,7073,7178,7265,7331,7369,7369,7321,7251,7168,7074,6965,6834,6693,6546,6393,6229,6044,5853,5643,5436,5218,4997,4769,4551,4327,4091,3861,3631,3401,3194,2989,2786,2582,2390,2205,2039,1877,1713,1540,1379,1243,1114,984,867,756,649,574,496,421,354,312,265,213,171,132,108,80,67,45,34,31,33,34,28,32,35,37,39,44,46,50,55,54,45,40,35,34,39,37,39,46,57,64,66,72,68,71,73,67,70,89,116,133,153,176,198,224,238,242,240,235,239,237,236,236,239,242,247,256,255,264,268,266,266,265,278,300,324,337,357,381,406,425,436,438,442,442,445,445,445,447,441,446,445,450,454,459,459,466,473,475,494,511,533,554,575,595,612,645,669,691,723,773,835,902,992,1076,1173,1290,1406,1532,1669,1827,1987,2149,2326,2512,2711,2909,3114,3314,3523,3743,3945,4136,4310,4471,4606,4718,4802,4860,4895,4901,4887,4843,4768,4674,4553,4401,4239,4056,3859,3654,3443,3220,2998,2787,2586,2383,2175,1979,1802,1634,1486,1324,1162,1011,861,699,510,302,60,-193,-478,-780,-1065,-1306,-1455,-1488,-1383,-1032,-401,535,1741,3153,4724,6411,8150,9800,11238,12365,13134,13526,13515,13027,12123,10792,9183,7370,5485,3611,1852,306,-966,-1914,-2553,-2900,-2998,-2897,-2640,-2268,-1868,-1456,-1052,-683,-366,-98,104,256,396,520,611,686,764,833,917,1006,1092,1181,1284,1411,1529,1666,1813,1957,2106,2271,2430,2589,2760,2932,3101,3285,3475,3658,3858,4054,4251,4449,4651,4865,5083,5291,5488,5682,5871,6047,6211,6348,6490,6640,6782,6914,7031,7125,7205,7254,7268,7243,7194,7115,7030,6932,6810,6683,6554,6413,6258,6084,5901,5698,5504,5298,5078,4845,4618,4392,4162,3929,3704,3477,3258,3050,2843,2644,2441,2265,2086,1914,1750,1578,1410,1267,1146,1015,896,779,659,578,512,429,353,294,241,188,155,116,76,48,23,-2,-19,-23,-31,-30,-20,-11,-5,4,7,11,12,6,2,-2,1,2,5,12,17,20,17,16,16,14,10,9,11,19,25,34,36,61,82,95,115,136,160,183,204,202,209,222,230,230,227,229,236,248,255,255,262,264,268,268,270,265,271,289,301,324,354,379,400,420,436,441,446,455,451,448,445,446,445,442,441,431,434,437,438,441,442,450,467,487,504,530,555,578,602,625,650,679,710,743,789,849,923,1011,1102,1200,1312,1434,1572,1727,1889,2052,2222,2411,2600,2799,3006,3206,3412,3622,3833,4023,4212,4386,4533,4656,4756,4831,4884,4916,4915,4888,4829,4741,4643,4521,4366,4187,4001,3796,3595,3387,3170,2943,2732,2528,2319,2120,1924,1748,1572,1418,1258,1101,959,808,655,457,238,-11,-271,-554,-848,-1130,-1349,-1447,-1408,-1198,-751,-48,969,2290,3781,5427,7137,8855,10431,11817,12821,13404,13603,13370,12721,11671,10252,8531,6670,4781,2958,1283,-172,-1367,-2204,-2720,-2929,-2929,-2749,-2452,-2063,-1651,-1237,-850,-518,-219,26,211,349,481,592,679,757,828,890,976,1077,1169,1257,1370,1498,1621,1773,1915,2054,2209,2368,2517,2675,2855,3032,3221,3415,3591,3783,3991,4198,4400,4601,4810,5020,5238,5443,5645,5843,6022,6188,6334,6474,6615,6764,6891,7009,7117,7216,7283,7327,7333,7302,7240,7161,7072,6957,6822,6689,6549,6396,6232,6057,5864,5666,5470,5262,5040,4817,4592,4368,4137,3909,3677,3451,3245,3049,2845,2638,2443,2264,2087,1920,1756,1580,1423,1300,1173,1049,941,834,723,643,565,481,412,353,303,252,211,168,143,121,105,87,64,61,65,80,81,74,74,73,80,82,79,71,72,79,82,90,97,96,94,97,100,102,103,100,104,112,124,124,127,133,145,165,186,206,230,256,275,298,312,315,315,321,320,326,335,338,336,350,355,358,358,358,363,366,376,375,389,409,438,461,481,505,527,546,557,565,563,567,567,567,567,572,576,580,584,587,587,592,593,597,596,593,608,625,652,676,697,723,744,778,810,837,860,902,963,1027,1113,1200,1285,1385,1510,1642,1779,1942,2101,2269,2452,2642,2837,3031,3230,3428,3639,3853,4046,4240,4418,4590,4732,4845,4928,4986,5031,5049,5042,4996,4921,4833,4720,4582,4418,4245,4053,3852,3647,3427,3211,3003,2802,2595,2375,2172,1991,1832,1678,1525,1361,1213,1068,916,732,518,278,21,-262,-562,-856,-1106,-1282,-1334,-1264,-951,-365,509,1680,3057,4609,6287,8045,9713,11203,12412,13253,13732,13827,13405,12563,11299,9732,7938,6059,4156,2334,759,-573,-1573,-2279,-2678,-2835,-2752,-2520,-2160,-1762,-1351,-949,-571,-235,37,251,407,545,668,775,863,941,1014,1101,1192,1284,1379,1478,1599,1715,1846,1985,2124,2271,2431,2586,2745,2918,3095,3273,3470,3661,3849,4049,4253,4451,4652,4852,5056,5273,5487,5687,5881,6073,6253,6422,6576,6720,6870,7013,7139,7254,7357,7431,7484,7499,7475,7431,7362,7271,7175,7051,6919,6790,6656,6497,6331,6144,5944,5749,5554,5331,5103,4873,4646,4420,4194,3969,3737,3520,3316,3109,2908,2713,2526,2346,2172,2010,1832,1663,1518,1383,1257,1132,1018,900,818,745,663,590,521,468,419,374,332,303,280,260,237,215,208,205,195,188,192,194,203,209,211,213,214,214,213,214,213,215,218,222,225,229,227,227,234,236,239,241,250,256,263,267,277,294,310,331,351,372,395,417,430,435,443,451,454,461,461,461,464,472,472,468,469,471,472,472,477,485,500,523,546,563,588,615,633,648,658,664,670,676,676,679,681,682,688,692,692,692,693,694,693,698,697,699,714,735,759,777,799,817,839,872,896,915,951,1002,1066,1149,1244,1327,1426,1546,1668,1804,1956,2110,2265,2433,2617,2801,3008,3210,3414,3622,3840,4052,4249,4441,4612,4771,4896,4997,5071,5125,5161,5169,5149,5087,5001,4896,4776,4630,4462,4272,4073,3870,3675,3454,3230,3015,2811,2592,2389,2200,2015,1849,1700,1536,1372,1240,1088,923,726,506,257,-6,-287,-592,-881,-1105,-1219,-1211,-1034,-639,18,956,2250,3716,5352,7061,8789,10417,11855,12963,13615,13882,13722,13148,12170,10800,9089,7242,5340,3500,1778,271,-985,-1880,-2424,-2695,-2727,-2587,-2307,-1927,-1503,-1097,-703,-349,-47,208,405,553,678,793,892,968,1043,1113,1202,1289,1385,1468,1567,1684,1807,1953,2100,2246,2406,2574,2730,2896,3075,3245,3432,3626,3805,3997,4210,4415,4622,4832,5035,5235,5446,5640,5836,6028,6212,6379,6537,6682,6831,6988,7135,7266,7371,7463,7543,7588,7597,7568,7511,7430,7350,7248,7116,6983,6845,6694,6531,6354,6162,5954,5755,5542,5320,5094,4869,4642,4411,4181,3950,3723,3511,3309,3104,2893,2694,2508,2335,2169,2005,1827,1664,1531,1405,1283,1165,1053,942,860,781,700,634,577,526,472,438,400,368,345,323,300,287,283,275,268,272,272,273,274,272,274,281,288,290,293,295,296,291,289,285,286,290,285,287,285,293,296,299,299,294,291,302,327,352,378,397,420,449,482,494,492,491,497,504,507,505,505,502,511,516,515,517,514,519,521,527,525,531,552,574,599,621,644,670,698,716,719,723,726,726,726,724,721,717,715,713,708,710,710,712,714,722,726,746,770,794,822,842,867,884,909,932,954,978,1011,1068,1132,1215,1305,1398,1504,1623,1750,1891,2041,2207,2366,2543,2734,2932,3132,3319,3523,3726,3948,4160,4352,4533,4699,4860,4981,5078,5148,5186,5201,5192,5154,5078,4981,4868,4725,4568,4393,4203,3999,3798,3588,3365,3141,2929,2724,2510,2311,2125,1956,1802,1655,1489,1329,1194,1034,853,646,409,162,-106,-394,-697,-955,-1142,-1228,-1161,-905,-366,450,1576,2917,4435,6101,7860,9552,11088,12341,13257,13794,13966,13638,12844,11660,10132,8383,6503,4597,2745,1116,-266,-1339,-2099,-2554,-2757,-2703,-2478,-2131,-1724,-1312,-907,-525,-184,95,312,471,606,730,837,924,1002,1072,1153,1237,1327,1422,1523,1638,1760,1887,2023,2163,2315,2472,2631,2791,2962,3133,3313,3513,3700,3882,4083,4283,4485,4693,4897,5102,5315,5526,5717,5913,6099,6274,6440,6581,6719,6866,7016,7151,7269,7370,7454,7514,7550,7541,7501,7435,7352,7252,7136,6997,6860,6720,6571,6397,6215,6025,5825,5626,5414,5185,4950,4723,4503,4269,4041,3821,3601,3387,3186,2979,2772,2592,2408,2227,2055,1884,1716,1568,1446,1309,1193,1085,972,886,816,731,650,580,522,465,422,374,331,307,286,268,250,243,242,240,237,235,228,228,232,233,232,229,236,236,245,247,244,248,255,262,267,261,261,256,260,256,254,255,255,271,269,284,312,337,359,380,399,422,448,459,454,452,452,451,454,453,456,462,465,472,481,490,487,485,486,493,499,517,536,558,591,616,641,661,678,684,684,689,690,693,696,692,697,700,710,707,705,708,703,706,701,702,702,723,742,755,780,804,833,853,882,905,931,972,1012,1073,1147,1230,1323,1420,1527,1640,1780,1928,2085,2250,2408,2577,2758,2964,3169,3364,3559,3771,3984,4187,4387,4559,4714,4843,4954,5034,5095,5128,5137,5115,5062,4982,4887,4770,4625,4465,4285,4085,3883,3686,3468,3236,3021,2820,2608,2396,2202,2015,1846,1698,1539,1371,1235,1102,949,763,549,305,50,-233,-541,-829,-1068,-1206,-1225,-1079,-738,-120,794,2023,3456,5052,6751,8471,10130,11593,12743,13454,13794,13720,13225,12325,11046,9379,7549,5652,3796,2044,499,-804,-1785,-2371,-2681,-2742,-2623,-2360,-1995,-1581,-1162,-761,-399,-93,173,379,537,673,784,874,949,1025,1095,1177,1261,1345,1431,1534,1652,1777,1911,2059,2207,2364,2531,2686,2850,3033,3216,3392,3585,3765,3947,4150,4354,4549,4748,4955,5157,5375,5585,5779,5974,6157,6331,6487,6629,6769,6921,7062,7190,7301,7400,7474,7529,7543,7520,7470,7398,7306,7196,7065,6930,6791,6644,6487,6313,6128,5930,5733,5526,5303,5081,4854,4625,4396,4170,3944,3725,3511,3310,3099,2897,2697,2514,2333,2162,2002,1826,1664,1530,1402,1279,1168,1057,942,856,775,690,615,553,502,454,409,366,339,319,297,274,249,239,240,243,244,245,250,253,251,254,253,246,247,244,247,252,257,264,273,289,297,307,310,312,313,310,305,299,292,284,285,303,327,350,379,411,436,462,481,487,491,495,498,499,502,507,512,517,521,531,532,535,542,544,550,550,560,576,600,619,632,652,667,686,704,702,700,702,711,711,719,721,719,724,728,726,724,733,733,734,734,734,750,775,796,812,838,869,896,924,949,972,1002,1041,1086,1148,1222,1300,1391,1494,1612,1737,1873,2017,2184,2357,2529,2708,2897,3097,3296,3495,3692,3907,4115,4317,4496,4666,4818,4942,5039,5113,5158,5178,5180,5146,5072,4988,4882,4743,4591,4424,4235,4032,3831,3624,3409,3192,2987,2784,2568,2371,2187,2017,1851,1708,1538,1377,1241,1089,917,718,497,246,-28,-323,-615,-882,-1080,-1197,-1152,-928,-435,333,1387,2691,4159,5795,7525,9223,10789,12097,13076,13680,13882,13643,12922,11820,10343,8647,6797,4904,3080,1434,16,-1109,-1920,-2431,-2682,-2672,-2477,-2161,-1766,-1357,-940,-549,-200,90,327,501,640,765,873,960,1039,1107,1180,1268,1361,1453,1549,1657,1770,1890,2029,2167,2306,2459,2610,2766,2936,3120,3300,3496,3692,3879,4076,4278,4479,4675,4877,5079,5293,5509,5703,5907,6101,6291,6462,6612,6743,6894,7049,7187,7305,7411,7494,7559,7599,7593,7561,7501,7418,7321,7206,7085,6955,6820,6662,6496,6320,6131,5932,5732,5518,5297,5075,4851,4621,4402,4175,3955,3730,3518,3309,3103,2904,2705,2522,2340,2171,2010,1844,1695,1567,1444,1322,1207,1094,983,907,826,744,674,624,578,529,490,451,423,396,374,353,340,345,345,342,345,355,359,356,359,363,373,377,374,375,372,377,382,376,375,379,388,394,396,401,396,405,408,409,409,404,411,429,455,474,495,513,528,549,572
];


var splitPointer = 0;
const EraseWindow = 200;

var counter = 0;
function randomData() {
    value = EcgData[counter%EcgData.length];
    counter++;
    return {
        name: counter%EcgData.length,
        value: [
            counter%EcgData.length,
            Math.round(value)
        ]
    };
}

var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < EcgData.length; i++) {
    data.push(randomData());
}

option = {
    title: {
        text: '???? + ?????'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        splitLine: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        boundaryGap: [0, '100%'],
        splitLine: {
            show: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '????',
        type: 'line',
        showSymbol: false,
        hoverAnimation: false,
        data: data
    },
    {
        name: '????',
        type: 'line',
        showSymbol: false,
        hoverAnimation: false,
        data: data
    }]
};

function arrayRotate(arr, reverse) {
  if (reverse) arr.unshift(arr.pop());
  else arr.push(arr.shift());
  return arr;
}

setInterval(function () {
splitPointer = data.length - counter % data.length;
splitPointer = data.length - splitPointer;
var p1 = data.slice(0, splitPointer);
var p2 = data.slice(splitPointer + EraseWindow);
p2.pop();
counter++;

    myChart.setOption({
        series: [{
            data: p1
        },
        {
            data: p2
        }]
    });
}, 1);
```

As you could see each time triggering setOption with full data (shifted) and rendering it.

```js
myChart.setOption({
        series: [{
            data: p1
        },
        {
            data: p2
        }]
    });
```

But when I tried to add 4 such ECG Views  I started getting slow rendering and low FPS and many frames missed rendering.

[image]

But in an ECG data, we just need to render latest data received after clearing a rectangular portion.
Do we have an option to set only updated portion of the series data?

Meanwhile I  saw EChartsGL (https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-gl) for WebGL rendering. Is it possible to use echarts-gl for for real-time plotting of 2D points (ECG data)? Any example of using echarts-gl for 2D line rendering will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering graphics with Canvas. In theory it should give you better perfomance results.

```
const chart = echarts.init(dom, null, {renderer: 'canvas'});
```

Comment: I agree Canvas renderer gave better results in ECharts. But for more control over rendering and to use WebGL directly I ended up using Canvas + WebGL without relying on echarts. I have high performance expectation and in my case it is good to use drawing API's directly from WebGL on Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you just need to consistently get the X-axis right. For example, if we take values from 0 to 100 on the X-axis, I'll start at 0 and go up to 100, then restart at 0 when I get to 100, and so on. It is your responsibility to delete certain values before the given value, like 5-6 values as you mentioned, to create a "blank" space before the given value as your example shows.

The ECharts' example shown always takes new and increasing values on the X-axis, so the value always moves to the right.

#### Example

```js
/**
 ** Initialize
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = echarts.init(chartDom)

/**
 ** Data
 */
// example fix ECG values (1x)
const sampleECGData = [
  50, 49, 51, 58, 82, 81, 20, 24
]

// generate full ECG data values (infinite)
function generateECGData() {
  const data = []
  let x = 0
  while (data.length < 100) {
    for (const y of sampleECGData) {
      data.push([x, y])
      x++
      if (data.length >= 100) {
        break
      }
    }
  }
  return data
}

// started data
let data = generateECGData()

// simulate ECG data value changes
function simulateECG(index) {
  // just take the value that is 6 steps ahead of the current value and write it into the current value's place
  const newIndex = (index + 6) % 100
  
  // between the current index and the index that is 6 steps ahead, I set every Y value to null (0 is not suitable because the chart draws a line to 0)
  const range = newIndex > index ? data.slice(index + 1, newIndex) : [...data.slice(index + 1), ...data.slice(0, newIndex)];
  for (const i of range) {
    i[1] = null;
  }
  
  // just take the value that is 6 steps ahead of the current value and write it into the current value's place
  data[index][1] = data[newIndex][1]
}

let currentIndex = 0
setInterval(function() {
  simulateECG(currentIndex) // update current and next 5 values
  currentIndex++
  
  if (currentIndex >= 100) currentIndex = 0 // restart (in next interval)
  
  updateChart() // rerender
}, 200); // example infinite change ECG values

/**
 ** Chart
 */
function updateChart () {
  /**
   ** Option
   */
  const option = {
    grid: {
      left: '30px',
      right: '30px',
      top: '10px',
      bottom: '30px'
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'axis',
      formatter: function (params) {
        return 'X: ' + params[0].value[0] + '<br/>Y: ' + params[0].value[1];
      },
      axisPointer: {
        animation: false
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'value'
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true,
      data: data
    }]
  }

  /**
   ** Render Chart
   */
  chart.setOption(option)
}
// First render
updateChart()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 170px;"></div>
```

The logic of updating the data is up to you. In the example, in an infinite (but fast) loop, every 200ms, I iterate through the X axis ranging from 0 to 100, and I always update the value corresponding to the current X with the value 6 steps ahead of it. I set the Y values between them (current X and 6 steps ahead) to null to create a small gap between the old and new data as in reality.

So, the logic of updating the data is up to you. In the ECharts example you linked, they always removed the 0th data point and pushed a new one. Instead, I overwrite the Y values of my fixed-length array each time.

```js
// started data
let data = generateECGData()

// simulate ECG data value changes
function simulateECG(index) {
  // just take the value that is 6 steps ahead of the current value and write it into the current value's place
  const newIndex = (index + 6) % 100
  
  // between the current index and the index that is 6 steps ahead, I set every Y value to null (0 is not suitable because the chart draws a line to 0)
  const range = newIndex > index ? data.slice(index + 1, newIndex) : [...data.slice(index + 1), ...data.slice(0, newIndex)];
  for (const i of range) {
    i[1] = null;
  }
  
  // just take the value that is 6 steps ahead of the current value and write it into the current value's place
  data[index][1] = data[newIndex][1]
}

let currentIndex = 0
setInterval(function() {
  simulateECG(currentIndex) // update current and next 5 values
  currentIndex++
  
  if (currentIndex >= 100) currentIndex = 0 // restart (in next interval)
  
  updateChart() // rerender
}, 200); // example infinite change ECG values
```

The key is to somehow update the chart after modifying the `data` array and notify that the dataset has changed.

Of course, 100 data points are too few for a real ECG, but this was just an example. The more data you have, the more detailed and nicer the result will be.